# ReadLine() that uses a buffer?

Tags: java, android, out-of-memory, readline

im using BufferedReader to read content of a CSV file line by line :

```
    for (int i=0; ((line=br.readLine())!=null) ; i++) {
        String[] split = line.split(",");
        ts[i]=Double.parseDouble(split[0]);
        amp[i]=Double.parseDouble(split[1]);
    }
```

This loop runs about 150k iterations, the ts and amp arrays are preallocated and takes not alot more then 1mb each, and yet i am getting `out of memory exception`. at the beginning i thought it was that the arrays are too big but i am starting to think that it is `readLine()` and `split()` that causing this by allocating many String objects and filling up the heap, here is the logcat while running this loop :

```
11-21 08:12:16.277: D/dalvikvm(2351): GC_FOR_MALLOC freed 8640 objects / 519088 bytes in 31ms
11-21 08:12:16.377: D/dalvikvm(2351): GC_FOR_MALLOC freed 13943 objects / 617264 bytes in 34ms
11-21 08:12:16.467: D/dalvikvm(2351): GC_FOR_MALLOC freed 13073 objects / 578176 bytes in 31ms
11-21 08:12:16.567: D/dalvikvm(2351): GC_FOR_MALLOC freed 13079 objects / 578168 bytes in 32ms
11-21 08:12:16.657: D/dalvikvm(2351): GC_FOR_MALLOC freed 13073 objects / 578144 bytes in 31ms
11-21 08:12:16.747: D/dalvikvm(2351): GC_FOR_MALLOC freed 13073 objects / 578128 bytes in 31ms
11-21 08:12:16.837: D/dalvikvm(2351): GC_FOR_MALLOC freed 13075 objects / 578104 bytes in 31ms
11-21 08:12:16.927: D/dalvikvm(2351): GC_FOR_MALLOC freed 13073 objects / 578176 bytes in 31ms
11-21 08:12:17.017: D/dalvikvm(2351): GC_FOR_MALLOC freed 13073 objects / 578152 bytes in 31ms
11-21 08:12:17.107: D/dalvikvm(2351): GC_FOR_MALLOC freed 13076 objects / 578176 bytes in 31ms
11-21 08:12:17.197: D/dalvikvm(2351): GC_FOR_MALLOC freed 13077 objects / 578176 bytes in 31ms
11-21 08:12:17.227: D/dalvikvm(2351): GC_FOR_MALLOC freed 1417 objects / 88168 bytes in 28ms
11-21 08:12:17.237: I/dalvikvm-heap(2351): Grow heap (frag case) to 4.463MB for 278976-byte allocation
11-21 08:12:17.277: D/dalvikvm(2351): GC_FOR_MALLOC freed 0 objects / 0 bytes in 41ms
11-21 08:12:17.317: D/dalvikvm(2351): GC_FOR_MALLOC freed 100 objects / 3912 bytes in 45ms
11-21 08:12:17.317: I/dalvikvm-heap(2351): Grow heap (frag case) to 4.726MB for 278976-byte allocation
11-21 08:12:17.377: D/dalvikvm(2351): GC_FOR_MALLOC freed 0 objects / 0 bytes in 53ms
11-21 08:12:17.627: D/dalvikvm(2351): GC_FOR_MALLOC freed 16432 objects / 572048 bytes in 40ms
11-21 08:12:17.907: D/dalvikvm(2351): GC_FOR_MALLOC freed 21312 objects / 779968 bytes in 48ms
11-21 08:12:18.187: D/dalvikvm(2351): GC_FOR_MALLOC freed 21582 objects / 791496 bytes in 45ms
11-21 08:12:18.527: D/dalvikvm(2351): GC_FOR_MALLOC freed 21918 objects / 805336 bytes in 52ms
11-21 08:12:18.767: D/dalvikvm(2351): GC_FOR_MALLOC freed 22258 objects / 818384 bytes in 50ms
11-21 08:12:19.017: D/dalvikvm(2351): GC_FOR_MALLOC freed 22550 objects / 830456 bytes in 52ms
11-21 08:12:19.277: D/dalvikvm(2351): GC_FOR_MALLOC freed 24160 objects / 887640 bytes in 50ms
11-21 08:12:19.547: D/dalvikvm(2351): GC_FOR_MALLOC freed 24386 objects / 900944 bytes in 53ms
11-21 08:12:19.827: D/dalvikvm(2351): GC_FOR_MALLOC freed 24575 objects / 908088 bytes in 53ms
11-21 08:12:20.137: D/dalvikvm(2351): GC_FOR_MALLOC freed 24785 objects / 917320 bytes in 58ms
11-21 08:12:20.597: D/dalvikvm(2351): GC_FOR_MALLOC freed 24958 objects / 924104 bytes in 59ms
11-21 08:12:20.937: D/dalvikvm(2351): GC_FOR_MALLOC freed 25145 objects / 932488 bytes in 62ms
11-21 08:12:21.227: D/dalvikvm(2351): GC_FOR_MALLOC freed 25336 objects / 940096 bytes in 64ms
11-21 08:12:21.837: D/dalvikvm(2351): GC_FOR_MALLOC freed 26830 objects / 993552 bytes in 256ms
11-21 08:12:22.477: D/dalvikvm(2351): GC_FOR_MALLOC freed 26934 objects / 1001584 bytes in 65ms
11-21 08:12:22.797: D/dalvikvm(2351): GC_FOR_MALLOC freed 27056 objects / 1005400 bytes in 65ms
11-21 08:12:23.127: D/dalvikvm(2351): GC_FOR_MALLOC freed 27159 objects / 1009248 bytes in 75ms
11-21 08:12:23.467: D/dalvikvm(2351): GC_FOR_MALLOC freed 28594 objects / 1058760 bytes in 75ms
11-21 08:12:23.817: D/dalvikvm(2351): GC_FOR_MALLOC freed 28643 objects / 1065424 bytes in 70ms
11-21 08:12:24.157: D/dalvikvm(2351): GC_FOR_MALLOC freed 28650 objects / 1063104 bytes in 71ms
11-21 08:12:24.507: D/dalvikvm(2351): GC_FOR_MALLOC freed 30001 objects / 1110840 bytes in 76ms
11-21 08:12:24.837: D/dalvikvm(2351): GC_FOR_MALLOC freed 29989 objects / 1114480 bytes in 76ms
11-21 08:12:25.197: D/dalvikvm(2351): GC_FOR_MALLOC freed 29928 objects / 1112088 bytes in 82ms
11-21 08:12:25.547: D/dalvikvm(2351): GC_FOR_MALLOC freed 31223 objects / 1157600 bytes in 80ms
11-21 08:12:25.918: D/dalvikvm(2351): GC_FOR_MALLOC freed 31156 objects / 1158728 bytes in 75ms
11-21 08:12:26.297: D/dalvikvm(2351): GC_FOR_MALLOC freed 32364 objects / 1200176 bytes in 80ms
11-21 08:12:26.667: D/dalvikvm(2351): GC_FOR_MALLOC freed 32245 objects / 1199544 bytes in 78ms
11-21 08:12:27.047: D/dalvikvm(2351): GC_FOR_MALLOC freed 33392 objects / 1237880 bytes in 73ms
11-21 08:12:27.457: D/dalvikvm(2351): GC_FOR_MALLOC freed 33223 objects / 1236256 bytes in 83ms
11-21 08:12:27.857: D/dalvikvm(2351): GC_FOR_MALLOC freed 34326 objects / 1274488 bytes in 90ms
11-21 08:12:28.267: D/dalvikvm(2351): GC_FOR_MALLOC freed 35443 objects / 1316328 bytes in 87ms
11-21 08:12:28.667: D/dalvikvm(2351): GC_FOR_MALLOC freed 35154 objects / 1308232 bytes in 90ms
11-21 08:12:29.167: D/dalvikvm(2351): GC_FOR_MALLOC freed 36188 objects / 1343032 bytes in 88ms
11-21 08:12:29.597: D/dalvikvm(2351): GC_FOR_MALLOC freed 37185 objects / 1382272 bytes in 90ms
11-21 08:12:30.027: D/dalvikvm(2351): GC_FOR_MALLOC freed 36818 objects / 1369776 bytes in 96ms
11-21 08:12:30.507: D/dalvikvm(2351): GC_FOR_MALLOC freed 37768 objects / 1403688 bytes in 108ms
11-21 08:12:30.967: D/dalvikvm(2351): GC_FOR_MALLOC freed 38717 objects / 1439096 bytes in 98ms
11-21 08:12:31.437: D/dalvikvm(2351): GC_FOR_MALLOC freed 39601 objects / 1471320 bytes in 102ms
11-21 08:12:31.897: D/dalvikvm(2351): GC_FOR_MALLOC freed 40432 objects / 1502408 bytes in 103ms
11-21 08:12:32.377: D/dalvikvm(2351): GC_FOR_MALLOC freed 41252 objects / 1532248 bytes in 102ms
11-21 08:12:32.857: D/dalvikvm(2351): GC_FOR_MALLOC freed 40715 objects / 1516256 bytes in 107ms
11-21 08:12:33.337: D/dalvikvm(2351): GC_FOR_MALLOC freed 41442 objects / 1540168 bytes in 109ms
11-21 08:12:33.837: D/dalvikvm(2351): GC_FOR_MALLOC freed 42223 objects / 1568280 bytes in 114ms
11-21 08:12:34.357: D/dalvikvm(2351): GC_FOR_MALLOC freed 42918 objects / 1595072 bytes in 109ms
11-21 08:12:34.857: D/dalvikvm(2351): GC_FOR_MALLOC freed 43604 objects / 1621272 bytes in 111ms
11-21 08:12:35.387: D/dalvikvm(2351): GC_FOR_MALLOC freed 44236 objects / 1643136 bytes in 119ms
11-21 08:12:35.917: D/dalvikvm(2351): GC_FOR_MALLOC freed 44833 objects / 1667152 bytes in 125ms
11-21 08:12:36.457: D/dalvikvm(2351): GC_FOR_MALLOC freed 45441 objects / 1689152 bytes in 123ms
11-21 08:12:36.997: D/dalvikvm(2351): GC_FOR_MALLOC freed 46002 objects / 1710696 bytes in 126ms
11-21 08:12:37.327: D/dalvikvm(2351): GC_FOR_MALLOC freed 20464 objects / 838800 bytes in 109ms
11-21 08:12:37.327: I/dalvikvm-heap(2351): Grow heap (frag case) to 8.357MB for 278752-byte allocation
11-21 08:12:37.417: D/dalvikvm(2351): GC_FOR_MALLOC freed 624 objects / 28192 bytes in 88ms
11-21 08:12:37.417: I/dalvikvm-heap(2351): Grow heap (frag case) to 8.595MB for 278752-byte allocation
11-21 08:12:37.507: D/dalvikvm(2351): GC_FOR_MALLOC freed 605 objects / 26136 bytes in 94ms
11-21 08:12:37.627: D/dalvikvm(2351): GC_EXTERNAL_ALLOC freed 1771 objects / 79408 bytes in 95ms
11-21 08:12:37.677: I/global(2351): Default buffer size used in BufferedReader constructor. It would be better to be explicit if an 8k-char buffer is required.
11-21 08:12:38.147: D/dalvikvm(2351): GC_FOR_MALLOC freed 47316 objects / 1682624 bytes in 125ms
11-21 08:12:38.607: D/dalvikvm(2351): GC_FOR_MALLOC freed 50691 objects / 1886456 bytes in 125ms
11-21 08:12:39.077: D/dalvikvm(2351): GC_FOR_MALLOC freed 50346 objects / 1867368 bytes in 125ms
11-21 08:12:39.557: D/dalvikvm(2351): GC_FOR_MALLOC freed 50983 objects / 1860976 bytes in 134ms
11-21 08:12:40.007: D/dalvikvm(2351): GC_FOR_MALLOC freed 49459 objects / 1851056 bytes in 131ms
11-21 08:12:40.517: D/dalvikvm(2351): GC_FOR_MALLOC freed 50486 objects / 1842352 bytes in 135ms
11-21 08:12:40.797: D/dalvikvm(2351): GC_FOR_MALLOC freed 24273 objects / 970136 bytes in 121ms
11-21 08:12:40.797: I/dalvikvm-heap(2351): Grow heap (frag case) to 10.441MB for 46508-byte allocation
11-21 08:12:40.897: D/dalvikvm(2351): GC_FOR_MALLOC freed 1206 objects / 89576 bytes in 98ms
11-21 08:12:41.367: D/dalvikvm(2351): GC_FOR_MALLOC freed 50141 objects / 1769760 bytes in 128ms
11-21 08:12:41.847: D/dalvikvm(2351): GC_FOR_MALLOC freed 50484 objects / 1853208 bytes in 133ms
11-21 08:12:42.317: D/dalvikvm(2351): GC_FOR_MALLOC freed 50492 objects / 1842496 bytes in 135ms
11-21 08:12:42.517: D/dalvikvm(2351): GC_FOR_MALLOC freed 12082 objects / 502744 bytes in 110ms
11-21 08:12:42.517: I/dalvikvm-heap(2351): Grow heap (frag case) to 10.589MB for 69752-byte allocation
11-21 08:12:42.627: D/dalvikvm(2351): GC_FOR_MALLOC freed 410 objects / 66160 bytes in 106ms
11-21 08:12:42.727: D/dalvikvm(2351): GC_FOR_MALLOC freed 408 objects / 19520 bytes in 102ms
11-21 08:12:42.727: I/dalvikvm-heap(2351): Grow heap (frag case) to 10.574MB for 69752-byte allocation
11-21 08:12:42.847: D/dalvikvm(2351): GC_FOR_MALLOC freed 1 objects / 46512 bytes in 117ms
11-21 08:12:43.317: D/dalvikvm(2351): GC_FOR_MALLOC freed 48763 objects / 1708184 bytes in 136ms
11-21 08:12:43.807: D/dalvikvm(2351): GC_FOR_MALLOC freed 52176 objects / 1909352 bytes in 139ms
11-21 08:12:44.287: D/dalvikvm(2351): GC_FOR_MALLOC freed 50568 objects / 1848768 bytes in 140ms
11-21 08:12:44.747: D/dalvikvm(2351): GC_FOR_MALLOC freed 49024 objects / 1793368 bytes in 134ms
11-21 08:12:45.157: D/dalvikvm(2351): GC_FOR_MALLOC freed 39117 objects / 1451904 bytes in 135ms
11-21 08:12:45.157: I/dalvikvm-heap(2351): Grow heap (frag case) to 11.120MB for 104620-byte allocation
11-21 08:12:45.267: D/dalvikvm(2351): GC_FOR_MALLOC freed 395 objects / 88912 bytes in 107ms
11-21 08:12:45.367: D/dalvikvm(2351): GC_FOR_MALLOC freed 1380 objects / 67848 bytes in 103ms
11-21 08:12:45.367: I/dalvikvm-heap(2351): Grow heap (frag case) to 11.070MB for 104620-byte allocation
11-21 08:12:45.467: D/dalvikvm(2351): GC_FOR_MALLOC freed 596 objects / 98320 bytes in 100ms
11-21 08:12:45.957: D/dalvikvm(2351): GC_FOR_MALLOC freed 51102 objects / 1812792 bytes in 140ms
11-21 08:12:46.457: D/dalvikvm(2351): GC_FOR_MALLOC freed 50849 objects / 1862544 bytes in 148ms
11-21 08:12:46.927: D/dalvikvm(2351): GC_FOR_MALLOC freed 49318 objects / 1802448 bytes in 140ms
11-21 08:12:47.407: D/dalvikvm(2351): GC_FOR_MALLOC freed 49392 objects / 1802936 bytes in 143ms
11-21 08:12:47.887: D/dalvikvm(2351): GC_FOR_MALLOC freed 49495 objects / 1805800 bytes in 150ms
11-21 08:12:48.377: D/dalvikvm(2351): GC_FOR_MALLOC freed 49539 objects / 1806848 bytes in 148ms
11-21 08:12:48.857: D/dalvikvm(2351): GC_FOR_MALLOC freed 49652 objects / 1810752 bytes in 142ms
11-21 08:12:49.117: D/dalvikvm(2351): GC_FOR_MALLOC freed 17452 objects / 696544 bytes in 132ms
11-21 08:12:49.117: I/dalvikvm-heap(2351): Grow heap (frag case) to 11.520MB for 156920-byte allocation
11-21 08:12:49.237: D/dalvikvm(2351): GC_FOR_MALLOC freed 510 objects / 129792 bytes in 122ms
11-21 08:12:49.357: D/dalvikvm(2351): GC_FOR_MALLOC freed 786 objects / 37712 bytes in 121ms
11-21 08:12:49.357: I/dalvikvm-heap(2351): Grow heap (frag case) to 11.510MB for 156920-byte allocation
11-21 08:12:49.487: D/dalvikvm(2351): GC_FOR_MALLOC freed 1 objects / 104624 bytes in 131ms
11-21 08:12:49.987: D/dalvikvm(2351): GC_FOR_MALLOC freed 49227 objects / 1721856 bytes in 165ms
11-21 08:12:50.547: D/dalvikvm(2351): GC_FOR_MALLOC freed 53182 objects / 1943240 bytes in 155ms
11-21 08:12:51.067: D/dalvikvm(2351): GC_FOR_MALLOC freed 51447 objects / 1875984 bytes in 155ms
11-21 08:12:51.607: D/dalvikvm(2351): GC_FOR_MALLOC freed 49938 objects / 1820528 bytes in 157ms
11-21 08:12:52.117: D/dalvikvm(2351): GC_FOR_MALLOC freed 48500 objects / 1768472 bytes in 156ms
11-21 08:12:52.637: D/dalvikvm(2351): GC_FOR_MALLOC freed 48629 objects / 1771176 bytes in 164ms
11-21 08:12:53.157: D/dalvikvm(2351): GC_FOR_MALLOC freed 48672 objects / 1773880 bytes in 163ms
11-21 08:12:53.678: D/dalvikvm(2351): GC_FOR_MALLOC freed 48755 objects / 1777616 bytes in 164ms
11-21 08:12:54.197: D/dalvikvm(2351): GC_FOR_MALLOC freed 48814 objects / 1780776 bytes in 165ms
11-21 08:12:54.718: D/dalvikvm(2351): GC_FOR_MALLOC freed 48915 objects / 1783368 bytes in 164ms
11-21 08:12:55.237: D/dalvikvm(2351): GC_FOR_MALLOC freed 47448 objects / 1733344 bytes in 168ms
```

So i guess i must find an alternative to readLine() and split() to read a csv file in the format :

```
double , double \n
```

i guess it has to be a buffered line read that always uses the same buffer
Any suggestions of an already implemented class that gives that ability?

Comment: What do you want to do with arrays ts, amp? Save in memory? Run operations on their?
Did you considered the possibility of splitting the parsing and processing to some little groups?

Answer (score 0):

You can try (Java 7):

```
List<String> lines = Files.readAllLines(Paths.get(filepath), StandardCharsets.UTF_8);
```

or other way: `com.googlecode.jcsv.reader.CSVReader`.

Something like:

```
CSVReader<CSVFromat> sessionReader = new CSVReaderBuilder<CSVFromat>(csvFile).entryParser(new CSVEntryParser()).build();

List<CSVFromat> session = sessionReader.readAll();
```

It will convert file to `List`